# How to fix Warning: Cannot update a component (`Value`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback, vite

I facing a issue when I run the react js vite project, The codes looks correct but doesn't run the codes and showing **Warning: Cannot update a component (`Value`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Context.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
**

The page Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
Accordion,
AccordionItem,
AccordionItemHeading,
AccordionItemButton,
AccordionItemPanel,
AccordionItemState

} from 'react-accessible-accordion';

import {MdOutlineArrowDropDown} from 'react-icons/md';
import data from '../../utils/accordion';
import './value.css';

const Value = () => {
return (
<section className="v-wrapper"\>
<div className="padding innerWidth flexCenter v-container"\>
{/\* Left Side \*/}
<div className="v-left">
<div className="image-container">
<img src="./value.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div className="flexColStart v-right">
<span className="orangeText">Our Value</span>
<span className="secondaryText">Why Value </span>
<span className="secondaryText">Value description\</span>

                <Accordion
                className="accordion"
                allowMultipleExpanded={false}
                preExpanded={[0]}
                >
                 {data.map((item, i ) => {
                    
                    const [className, setClassName] = useState(null);
    
                        return (
                            <AccordionItem className={`accordionItem ${className}`} key={i} uuid={i}>
                                <AccordionItemHeading>
                                    <AccordionItemButton className="flexCenter accordionButton">
                                        <AccordionItemState>
                                            {({ expanded }) =>
                                            expanded 
                                            ? setClassName("expanded") 
                                            : setClassName("collapsed")
                                            }
    
                                        </AccordionItemState>
                                        <div className="flexCenter icon">{item.icon}</div>
                                        <span className="secondaryText">{item.heading}</span>
                                        <div className="flexCenter icon">
                                            <MdOutlineArrowDropDown size={20}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </AccordionItemButton>
                                </AccordionItemHeading>
                                <AccordionItemPanel>
                                    <p className="secondaryText">{item.detail}</p>
                                </AccordionItemPanel>
                            </AccordionItem>
                        );
                    })}
                
                </Accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

)
}

export default Value;
```

Tried to delete the setState lines but showing same

Comment: Try reproducing the problem on https://codesandbox.io/ or any other online service