# How to fix Warning: Cannot update a component (`Page`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, vite

I facing a issue when I run the react js vite project, The codes looks correct but doesn't run the codes and showing **Warning: Cannot update a component (Value) while rendering a different component (Context.Consumer). To locate the bad setState() call inside Context.Consumer, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render **

The page Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
Accordion,
AccordionItem,
AccordionItemHeading,
AccordionItemButton,
AccordionItemPanel,
AccordionItemState

} from 'react-accessible-accordion';

import {MdOutlineArrowDropDown} from 'react-icons/md';
import data from '../../utils/accordion';
import './value.css';

const Value = () => {
return (
<section className="v-wrapper"\>
<div className="padding innerWidth flexCenter v-container"\>
{/* Left Side */}
<div className="v-left">
<div className="image-container">
<img src="./value.png" />
</div>
</div>
<div className="flexColStart v-right">
<span className="orangeText">Title</span>
<span className="secondaryText">Why </span>
<span className="secondaryText"> description\</span>

                <Accordion
                className="accordion"
                allowMultipleExpanded={false}
                preExpanded={[0]}
                >
                 {data.map((item, i ) => {
                    
                    const [className, setClassName] = useState(null);
    
                        return (
                            <AccordionItem className={`accordionItem ${className}`} key={i} uuid={i}>
                                <AccordionItemHeading>
                                    <AccordionItemButton className="flexCenter accordionButton">
                                        <AccordionItemState>
                                            {({ expanded }) =>
                                            expanded 
                                            ? setClassName("expanded") 
                                            : setClassName("collapsed")
                                            }
    
                                        </AccordionItemState>
                                        <div className="flexCenter icon">{item.icon}</div>
                                        <span className="secondaryText">{item.heading}</span>
                                        <div className="flexCenter icon">
                                            <MdOutlineArrowDropDown size={20}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </AccordionItemButton>
                                </AccordionItemHeading>
                                <AccordionItemPanel>
                                    <p className="secondaryText">{item.detail}</p>
                                </AccordionItemPanel>
                            </AccordionItem>
                        );
                    })}
                
                </Accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

)
}

export default Value;
```

I tried to delete setState and comment the full page content but browser still showing the problem

Comment: The question is not related to Vue. Did you try to do what the error suggests, "follow the stack trace as described"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Warning: Cannot update a component (\`Value\`) while rendering a different component (\`Context.Consumer\`). To locate the bad setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971017/how-to-fix-warning-cannot-update-a-component-value-while-rendering-a-differ)

Answer (score 0):

I think useState shouldn't be used inside a callback. You can use useRef hook instead.
The modified code will be:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const Values = () => {
  const classNameRef = useRef(null);

  // Rest of the component

  // Inside the map function, replace useState with ref
  {
    data.map((item, i) => {
      const setClassName = (value) => {
        classNameRef.current = value;
      };
      return (
        <AccordionItem className={`accordianItem ${classNameRef.current}`} key={i} uuid={i}>
          <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton className='flexCenter accordianButton'>
              <AccordionItemState>
                {({ expanded }) => expanded ? setClassName("expanded") : setClassName("collapsed")}
              </AccordionItemState>
              {/* ... rest of the code */}
            </AccordionItemButton>
          </AccordionItemHeading>
          {/* ... rest of the code */}
        </AccordionItem>
      )
    })
  }
}
```